# How might I split a string by every nth character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I need to split a string into an array; my string will look something like this:

```
"6 3\n-3 30 23 -1 0 4 5\n5 4\n13 -3 -20 -4 -1"
```

Expanded, that looks like this:

```
"6 3
-3 30 23 -1 0 4 5
5 4
13 -3 -20 -4 -1"
```

I want to split this string into an array like this:

```
["6 3\n-3 30 23 -1 0 4 5","5 4\n13 -3 -20 -4 -1"]
```

That is, split the original string at every second `\n` character. I would also like a way to split some string at every `n`th appearance of some character. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @mico 'SO'? Not sure what that means. Regardless, I really am lost as to the solution. It has escaped me thus far.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: StackOverflow.

Comment: @LyeFish Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware that it was also a verb :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` instead:

```
var s = "6 3\n-3 30 23 -1 0 4 5\n5 4\n13 -3 -20 -4 -1";
var m = s.match(/[^\n]+\n[^\n]+/g);
//=> ["6 3\n-3 30 23 -1 0 4 5", "5 4\n13 -3 -20 -4 -1"]
```

Comment: it will fail if there are consecutive newlines.

Comment: I can refine it further but would like to see more test cases from OP